DM99 Part Functionality
I have an anti theft computer PCB from a 1974 Corvette and am trying to draw it out schematically to find out what it does. It has a component I cannot seem to find anything on marked DM99 with smaller markings of 519 and 7322 (see photo below). Does anyone know what this component does?



please show both sides of the PCB

Given the age, potentially a custom numbered IC, so identification without a schematic will be difficult. The 7322 will likely be a date code (22nd week in 1973).

IIRC GM Delco was really big on house-numbered part in that era anyway, and a security system is even more likely than usual to have such markings. So you might have better luck asking GM or 'vette specialists as opposed to electronics folks.

@jsotola - photo of the bottom side was added.

@SpehroPefhany - thank you - good idea. I will reach out!
